# Hybrid MQTT broker WebSockets + TCP

Tags: websocket, mqtt

I am new to MQTT and I was wondering whether there are any existing MQTT brokers capable of simultaneous TCP an WS connectivity? For example I would like a webpage subscribe for a topic over WS MQTT and some other device send messages by TCP.

I only worked with MQTTnet that seems to be able to start MQTT server of only one type TCP or WS.

Comment: Edit the question to include how you've setup MQTTnet so somebody can help you modify it to listen for both native MQTT and MQTT over Websockets. The doc's imply it should be possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most available MQTT brokers support both MQTT and MQTT over Websockets.

Support for multiple listeners is pretty standard feature as it means they can also support TLS secured listeners as well as unencrypted connections for both native MQTT and MQTT over Websockets.

IBM's Messagesight device can even share the same port for native MQTT and MQTT over Websockets (this is not how most brokers work and may be covered by patent).

Answer (score 0):

If you use different clientIDs for the webpage and devices, then what you are looking for can be achieved. Below you can find what brokers provide WS: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_MQTT_implementations